# Binding StringFormat giving incorrect result

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, string-formatting

For some reason using `Content="{Binding Time, StringFormat=t}` is still giving me a long date. The backing field is a `DateTime` property initialised with `DateTime.Now` but no matter what string format I try it still shows the full date...

I would like only to see HH:mm tt

Any ideas?

XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="ArgosSystem.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:ArgosSystem"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="1280" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type loc:Picknote}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200" MinWidth="200" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="350" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Content="{Binding Time, StringFormat=t}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  Foreground="IndianRed" FontSize="36" Grid.Column="0" />
                <Label Content="{Binding Customer}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="IndianRed" FontSize="36" Grid.Column="1" />
                <Label Content="{Binding PicknoteNo}"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  Foreground="IndianRed" FontSize="36" Grid.Column="2" />
                <Label Content="{Binding Qty}"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  Foreground="IndianRed" FontSize="36" Grid.Column="3" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Background="Black">
        <DockPanel>
            <ScrollViewer Name="lstPicknoteScroll" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ItemsControl Name="lstPicknotes" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  IsTabStop="False" Foreground="Cornsilk" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C# :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<Picknote> picknotes = new ObservableCollection<Picknote>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lstPicknotes.DataContext = picknotes;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        picknotes.Add(new Picknote
        {
            Time = DateTime.Now,
            Customer = "REED FOR SPEED",
            PicknoteNo = "PKN767677",
            Qty = 100
        });

        picknotes.Add(new Picknote
        {
            Time = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2),
            Customer = "F1 AUTOMOTIVE",
            PicknoteNo = "PKN767677",
            Qty = 50
        });
        picknotes.Add(new Picknote
        {
            Time = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1),
            Customer = "FERGUSENS",
            PicknoteNo = "PKN767677",
            Qty = 10
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***StringFormat*** works on properties of type string. The Content property is of type Object so you need to specify the format using ***ContentStringFormat*** property of Label control.

```
<Label Content="{Binding Time}" ContentStringFormat="t" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  Foreground="IndianRed" FontSize="36" Grid.Column="0" />
```